# Scala matching a specific node in xml

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

I have xml that looks like this:

```
val xml =
<plugins> 
  <plugin type="x">plugin x</plugin>
  <plugin type="y">plugin y</plugin>
</plugins>
```

I am trying to write a `match` statement that finds the plugin with the attribute `type="x"`. I tried:

```
xml match {
  case <plugin type="x">{contents}</plugin> => println(contents)
  case _ => println("not found")
}
```

but I got a syntax error on the `type="x"` attribute.

Is there a way to do this match?

Thanks.